# WSO2 : Building micro-integrator project from the source failing

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb, wso2-enterprise-integrator

I need to update some of the internal jars in my micro-integrator project (v4.0.0) to a specific version, and i'm doing that by building it from the source repo [here](https://github.com/wso2/micro-integrator/tree/v4.0.0) .
I've downgraded my java home to 8 as specified in the requirements, and am upgrading the jars required in the pom.xml file one by one and then building so that I can isolate and identify the errors(if any). I found that when I upgraded my netty.version in the pom to 4.1.86.Final, I get the following error:
*......*

> Installing org.wso2.micro.integrator.security.server.feature.group
> 4.0.0.  Installing org.wso2.micro.integrator.crypto.feature.group 4.0.0.  Installing org.wso2.micro.integrator.dataservices.server.feature.group 4.0.0.
> Installation failed. Cannot complete the install because one or more
> required items could not be found.
> Software being installed:
> org.wso2.micro.integrator.websocket.feature 4.0.0
> (org.wso2.micro.integrator.websocket.feature.group 4.0.0)
> Missing
> requirement: Netty/Handler 4.1.86.Final (io.netty.handler
> 4.1.86.Final) requires 'package io.netty.channel.unix [4.1.0,5.0.0)' but it could not be found
> Cannot satisfy dependency:   From:
> Netty/Codec/HTTP 4.1.86.Final (io.netty.codec-http 4.1.86.Final)   To:
> package io.netty.handler.ssl [4.1.0,5.0.0)
> Cannot satisfy dependency:
> From: org.wso2.micro.integrator.websocket.feature 4.0.0
> (org.wso2.micro.integrator.websocket.feature.group 4.0.0)   To:
> io.netty.codec-http [4.1.86.Final]

I've looked though the p2-profile repo and the package io.netty.channel.unix is being referenced in the \micro-integrator\p2-profile\target\p2-repo\content.xml file.

I would like to know how I can add this package to the build. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just migrate your Artifacts to the latest Micro Integrator version(4.2) where the Netty version is upgraded. You can see the updated version [here](https://github.com/wso2/micro-integrator/blob/v4.2.0/pom.xml#L1646).